# add vertical space to table row (\rule{0pt}{4ex} not working properly)

Tags: tabularx, cline

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{L{2cm} L{2cm} L{2cm} L{2cm} L{2cm} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{start value} &  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{solution} \\
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
a & b &  & d & e \rule{0pt}{4ex} \\
\midrule 
10& 1000 & & 20 & 2000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The command \rule{0pt}{4ex} adds the desired vertical space, however, the content of the last cell (e) is below the other cell contents.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Aren't you using `m` columns?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You get vertical middle alignment, don't you? The “e” *has* to be moved down because the whole rule is vertically centered.

Comment: How can I make the e to be on the same level as a,b,c,d?

Comment: Just don't add the rule and, if you want more vertical space above that row, use `\addlinespace`. Besides, use `\cmidrule` and not `\cline`. Instead of such complicated setting for `L`, use `w{l}{2cm}` for fixed width columns.

Comment: Feel free to write this in an answer. My issue is solved.